# Dial pad to get phone number (with Android button images)

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to get user input phone number, and my requirement is "on every button press my application analyze the input if length increased 10 digits than i want to enable 'Next' button".

I am planning to do it with a custom dialing pad that should look like android built-in dialing pad (image attached)...

can i use standard android dialing pad to achieve my requirement or should i develop my own dialing pad?

[image: Dial Pad]

Answer (score 1):

There is no "standard android dialing pad".  Every phone ships their own dialer, which may or may not be the one google wrote.  There is no dialing pad widget.  You can ask for a numeric keyboard and force the keyboard to show, but it may have any format, and may not just be those 9 keys.  If you want this, you're going to have to write it from scratch (or find a pre-existing library).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KeyboardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html). Design your own key layout in xml and put it anywhere on your layout. You can do whatever you want with it, like handle keypresses and change the key labels on run-time. Also, you need change input type of the editable field to something that won't trigger the OS (IME) keyboard, or else you will end up with both your custom keyboard as a view and the regular one.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myBox =EditText.getText().toString();
if(myBox.length()<=9)
{
EditText.setOnEditorActionListener();
}
```

This may help you.